# Entity Framework 6: Lazy loading doesn't work when classes are internal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I have lazy loading enabled:

[image]

When I set my entity class Access to 'public, lazy loading works fine:

[image]
In the example above, I'm able to navigate from Address to City.

However, if I change the entity class Access to 'internal', then lazy loading stops working and I can no longer navigate from Address to City if I don't eager load City:

[image]

[image]

Why does lazy loading stop working for internal classes?  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entity must be `public`, it's a requirement for Entity Framework to be able to inherit from it and create a proxy at runtime (that adds all the EF internal stuff in the overridden `virtual` navigation properties).

See [Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx) on MSDN.